# Access Docker hosted web application from Host machine

Tags: docker, web-applications, localhost

I have created a php web application and hosted it in Docker.
Now Im trying to access the application from the host machine(not through docker) and Im unable to open it.Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Details-
OS - Catalina

```
Accessing :- http://localhost:60
Error-
This page isn’t workinglocalhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE


Followed the below steps :-
Shrutis-MacBook-Pro:MyDockerImages shrutipatnaik$ ls
index.php       world.txt
Dockerfile      

Shrutis-MacBook-Pro:MyDockerImages shrutipatnaik$ docker build -t jenkins_php .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  653.8MB
Step 1/3 : FROM php:7.4-apache
---> 05e7c943eaa9
Step 2/3 : COPY . /var/www/html
---> e30136f8e0c7
Step 3/3 : CMD ls &&     whoami &&     pwd ;
---> Running in 4c29020952fb
Removing intermediate container 4c29020952fb
---> dd0a9d7f8ccd
Successfully built dd0a9d7f8ccd
Successfully tagged jenkins_php:latest


Shrutis-MacBook-Pro:MyDockerImages shrutipatnaik$docker run -it -d -p 60:60 
jenkins_php:latest /bin/sh
26e3590f0e6a249f26251c33020a8180610ce07ff11004dc3dc2460a3aa41790



Shrutis-MacBook-Pro:MyDockerImages shrutipatnaik$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             
STATUS                      PORTS                                NAMES
26e3590f0e6a        jenkins_php:latest    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 hours ago         
Up 6 hours                  60/udp, 0.0.0.0:60->60/tcp, 80/tcp   kind_chatelet
```

Comment: I don't use MacOS but I believe you can't use `localhost` to access Docker containers (running on a VM) from the host. Instead you can use `host.internal.docker`. Also, you reference ports 60 and port 80. Which port is the PHP app serving?

Answer (score 0):

OK two things:

first - when you run the container with the `/bin/sh` command in the end that's the command the container is running, not your web app.
See your used docker image [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/layers/php/library/php/7.4-apache/images/sha256-88c3519e2e6d47029262d57b201aa33aee6beb176b4276f3d7ca411bd5afeb89?context=explore) and `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` commands.

when you add the command in the end of the `docker run` command you override the preconfigured startup commands:

> Usage:  docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]

For that run `docker run -dp 60:60 jenkins_php:latest`

example with nginx:

when running like suggested in question:

```
docker run -itdp 80:80 nginx /bin/sh
```

We get trying to access through chrome:

[image: chrome error message image]

when running "regularly" with:

```
docker run -dp 80:80 nginx
```

or even

```
docker run -itdp 80:80 nginx
```

We get trying to access through chrome:

[image: nginx is up and working image]

and in either case when running `docker ps` it doesn't show the new command but the old entry-point script (just like in the question) even though it was overridden:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
3fe92585a40c   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp   adoring_heisenberg
```

second - it is also possible that after fixing that it wont work cause you also publish port 80/tcp and unless you specifically chose that it would make more sense to publish on 80 by default so I'd check that along the way.

for that run `docker run -dp 80:80 jenkins_php:latest`

if we try to replicate like in the previous misconfiguration we get the same error

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                           NAMES
146d05cc5275   nginx     "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 seconds ago   Up 2 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->1000/tcp, :::80->1000/tcp   goofy_lamport
```

> localhost didn’t send any data.
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: I tried the below as suggested without /bin/sh ,the container exited & the same error (This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect).

Comment: MacBook$ docker run -itdp 160:160 jenkins_php:latest nginx  
d914159e6aa2deab1280e36774ea7a2f19fcaad67f836a9d626bbf04e99d2e4f

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS                                NAMES
d914159e6aa2        jenkins_php:latest    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (127) 2 minutes ago                                        objective_davinci

Comment: When I’m trying with 80:80 ,I’m getting the below error.
MacBook$docker run -itdp 80:80 jenkins_php:latest apache
eaf3ec71bb04b34ed1be848ff347fe463d258eaba8871dfd99bf4d6e25ec9046
docker: Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use.

Comment: it maybe because port 80 is already used by a container or another program, you dont have to bind to port 80 on the host just in the container. use port 8080 instead for example `8080:80`

Comment: tried with 8080:80, I'm still getting ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE dont know why. Also the container status shows exited.

Comment: If you get it's logs with `docker logs container-name` what does it return?

Comment: You don't need to add `apache` at the end, the command you've set in the ENTRYPOINT or CMD should run instead. Also, you don't have the apache command in the container, if you it's path give the full path to it, though again you shouldn't anyway

Comment: $ docker run -itdp 8080:80 jenkins_php:latest       
f8aa8087f3d24f35d6fde3b6715f7bea8d555ac74b1234df4e60d2d791907075
$docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       
f8aa8087f3d2        jenkins_php:latest    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   23 seconds ago      Exited (0) 22 seconds ago
$ docker logs f8aa8087f3d2
Dockerfile_works   hello.sh  world.txtDockerfile   Dockerfile_works2  index.php
Dockerfile_issue  Dockerfile_works3  outDockerfile_ubuntu_works  bck_Dockerfile1    universe.py root /var/www/html
$

Comment: Please add it with format to the question instead under "update"

Comment: $ docker run -itdp 8080:80 jenkins_php:latest       
f8aa8087f3d24f35d6fde3b6715f7bea8d555ac74b1234df4e60d2d791907075

Comment: $docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS
f8aa8087f3d2        jenkins_php:latest    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   23 seconds ago      Exited (0) 22 seconds ago

Comment: $ docker logs f8aa8087f3d2

Dockerfile_works   hello.sh world.txt Dockerfile Dockerfile_works2  index.php Dockerfile_issue  Dockerfile_works3  out
Dockerfile_ubuntu_works  bck_Dockerfile1    universe.py root /var/www/html
$

Comment: is the format ok or kindly let me know how can I improve it?

Comment: did you add the file names after the `docker logs` command?

Comment: The filenames came out as the output in "docker logs <container id>" . The dockerfile and the other files were present in my the host machine in my dockerfile path. Forgot to mention one point is I have jenkins hosted in my localhost:8080 does cause this ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for 8080:80 ? (I'm a new bee)

Comment: Sorry @ShrutiPatnaik I'm a bit confused after all the changes, please add to your question with the "edit" button your Dockerfile you use, the latest command you're using to run the container and `docker ps -a` command output. this will help me help you faster and in an orderly manner

Comment: @ShrutiPatnaik if this answer helped you please accept it